# Windows 7 IP routing

Tags: windows-7, networking, routing

I'm really stuck on this one and I have been told stack over flow is a great place to come for advice.

I have a machine running Windows 7 Professional with two internal gigabit NICs. I have enabled IP routing using the registry key "IPEnableRouter", setting it to 1.

This is the output of ipconfig:

```
C:\Users\testlab>ipconfig /all

Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : testlab-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : Yes
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : goose.com

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 4:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : goose.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : D-Link DGE-528T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-64-01-73-A8-4G
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 10.10.10.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : goose.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : B1-AE-C9-1A-59-13
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.65.65(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 172.16.0.254
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 172.20.220.26
                                       10.10.10.2
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter Local Area Connection* 11:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.bskyb.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : goose.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes


Routing table:

C:\Users\testlab>route print
===========================================================================
Interface List
 17...00 24 11 83 a8 4D ......D-Link DGE-528T Gigabit Ethernet Adapter
 11...b3 ae D5 1A 19 79 ......Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
 12...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
 14...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.16.0.254     172.16.65.65    266
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
       172.16.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link      172.16.65.65    266
     172.16.65.65  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.65.65    266
   172.16.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.65.65    266
      192.168.1.0    255.255.255.0         On-link       192.168.1.1    266
      192.168.1.1  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.1    266
    192.168.1.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.1    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link      172.16.65.65    266
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link       192.168.1.1    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    306
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link      172.16.65.65    266
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link       192.168.1.1    266
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  Network Address          Netmask  Gateway Address  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     172.16.0.254  Default
===========================================================================

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    306 ::1/128                  On-link
  1    306 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

I've set this up on a couple of machines before years ago and it worked fine, I guess I am just forgetting something, but it is driving me crazy now. From the 192.168.1 network I can ping 192.168.1.1 and 172.16.65.65, but not any of the other hosts on the 172.16 network. So all the hosts in the 192 network have no access.

I've even tried enabling the routing and remote access service, but that made no difference. I'm tried with all firewalls disabled as well to ensure it wasn't being blocked.

When I trace a ping from 192. to the internet it gets to 172.16.65.65 and then never moves on, it is like the machine just won't forward the packets on, but I do not know why.

Any advice or things to try would be very appreciated and if you need anymore information let me know.